# Using @Binding with type casting in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, binding, swiftui, property-wrapper

My data model:

```
class MyData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var aabbData = [AabbData]()
}

struct AbData: AabbData{
    var x = 0
}

protocol AabbData{

}
```

In my view code, i want to downcast aabbData's element to AbData type, and bind its x property to a control's value. So i try to code this:

```
@EnvironmentObject var data: MyData
let index = 0

//some other code

//method 1
Slider(value: ($data.aabbData[index] as! Binding<AbData>).x, in: -100...100, step: 1)
//error: Cast from 'Binding<AabbData>' to unrelated type 'Binding<AbData>' always fails

//method 2
Slider(value: Binding<Int>(
    get:{
        (data.aabbData[index] as! AbData).x
    },
    set:{
        (data.aabbData[index] as! AbData).x = $0
        //error: Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Int'
    }
), in: -100...100, step: 1)
```

The code is not working.
How can i bind the downcast value's property to control's value?

Comment: Generic types of related types aren't themselves related in Swift. In other words, `Foo<A>` is as different from `Foo<B>` as any other type, even if `A: B`

Comment: If you're going force-cast then `aabbData` is always `[AbData]` then there is no sense in this artificial making it `[AabbData]` at all. And by the way in majority of cases forget about casting in SwiftUI, for easiness and safeness of project code.

Comment: It's simplified code, aabbData is a array contains multiple different struct type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Binding` type allow for both reading and writing. Since you can't safely read the value of an `AabbData` and assume it's an `AbData` this cannot work.

If you want to try anyway, then you'll have to create a new Binding (possibly with the `Binding(get:set:)` constructor) that does the casting there.

For example, noting that this forced cast is probably not advisable for all the usual reasons:

```
let binding = Binding<AbData>(get: {
    data.aabbData[index] as! AbData
}, set: {
    data.aabbData[index] = $0
})
```

Comment: thanks. I try to create a new binding, but fail to create a correct setter to make data binding working. Could you show some code?

Comment: @swiftrustar sure

Comment: It's strange that there is no generic way of doing this. Rebinding works though. As shown in this example. Thanks!

Comment: @Sentry.co It's not so strange really, as this is essentially bypassing the type system. The type system makes this difficult to do because it's usually a bad idea, but forced downcasts allow the developer to assert that they know what they're doing, and to crash if they get it wrong.